# Quiero saber de que forma puedo visualizar los resultados de un modelo predictivo entrenado con Ai bulder en dataverse

Tags: microsoft, powerapps, predicción

Cargue una tabla de excel a dataverse y luego la tome y entrene un modelo predictivo con Ai  bulder, después de entrenar el modelo y publicarlo no he encontrado la forma de visualizar los resultados que arroja la predicción.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.